# How do I find the impulse response of the system given output and input signals?

Tags: convolution

I stumbled upon this question as I was solving my homework.
There is an input signal x(t).
[image]

and y(t) as an output signal.

[image]

My idea was to find the function of y(t) in terms of step function and then replace all step functions with delta Dirac function.

[image]

My question now is, do I treat step functions as the input impulse function disregarding all t's?

By placing  impulse function at T ,3T and 4T and letting it convolute with x(t), I can achieve the given output signal. But I would like to find it with the idea above. Thank you.

Comment: What about taking 2nd derivative of each signal?

Comment: u mean 2nd derivative of linear representatives and first derivative of step functions or 2nd of everything including t. So replacing inputs with delta functions isn't viable here if not is there any explanation? Ill try taking derivatives and put it on the post if my problems not cleared. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: 1/2a(2nd derivative of output function ) will be the impulse response i think but! But if you explain more about your idea and what you wanted to achieve maybe I can help you! And are sure that impulse at T,3T,4T is solution? Because to me impulse at origin should also be there !